# cast from string to HttpError or get it as HttpError from HttpResponseMessage, is it possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http, http-error

Is it possible to cast from string to HttpError object?

```
HttpResponseMessage response= 
 _controller.AddFeedback(Guid.NewGuid(),feedbackSessionDto);
            // Assert
       string message = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

the message is looks like this "{\"Message\":\"Error while updating\"}"

and i want the httpError

Comment: What do you mean by "the httpError"?

Comment: I want the message will be as HttpError class from system.Web.Http that i could take only the message as a result it will be only the string "Error while updating\"

Comment: Why not just parse the JSON? (I think HttpError exists to make it easy for ASP.NET users to *provide* error information - I don't think it maps to anything specific in HTTP itself, so I'd be surprised to see it from a client perspective.) I'm assuming that the backslashes you've included aren't actually in the string, and you've only shown them because the debugger has shown them...